# S3 File Transfers and Glue ETL

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, etl, aws-glue

I'm currently interning as a Data Engineer at a new company, and I've encountered a bit of a challenge in my first task. I'm hoping some of you with more experience can provide some guidance and resources.

Here's the issue:

Task: My assignment is to transfer data from one S3 bucket (let's call it Account A) to another S3 bucket (Account B). The source path is s3://X/Y, and the target path should be s3://X/Y/daily
X being bucket name.

Data Structure: Within the 'Y' directory in Account A, there are numerous folders, each named after a date (e.g., '2022-01-01'). Inside each of these date folders, there are multiple .csv files. My objective is to move all these folders and files to the target location while converting them to the Parquet format.

Challenges: I've attempted various methods to achieve this, but nothing seems to be working as expected. I believe setting up a Glue ETL job could be a solution(It's compulsory that it should be done through Glue ETL only), and I have the necessary permissions for both reading and writing in both S3 accounts. So, it doesn't appear to be a permissions issue.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance, guidance, or resources you can provide to help me tackle this task successfully. If you've worked with Glue ETL jobs for a similar scenario or have suggestions for alternative approaches, please share your insights.

Thank you all in advance for your support!

Challenges: I've attempted various methods to achieve this, but nothing seems to be working as expected. I believe setting up a Glue ETL job could be a solution(It's compulsory that it should be done through Glue ETL only), and I have the necessary permissions for both reading and writing in both S3 accounts. So, it doesn't appear to be a permissions issue.

Answer (score 1):

First, If you need to convert the data from CSV format to Parquet, then just copy doesn´t work. It is required to read the data and write a new set of files.

I am assuming all CSV files have the same structure (columns and types). If this is not the case, then you will be required to work in groups to process each of the different file structures.

Step 1.

In Spark (Glue in your case), read the CSV into a DataFrame using wildcards to read at the same time all **date folders**.

```
inputDF = spark.read.csv("s3://<basepath>/*/*.csv")
```

Step 2.

Add a column with the input filename to be able to extract the **date** from the path and use it in the next steps to generate the output folder

```
val input2DF = inputDF.withColumn("filename", input_file_name())
```

Step 3.

Add columns for each column that you want to use as an output partition (eg. year, month, day, or the whole date)

```
val input3DF = input2DF.withColumn("year", substr(filename, 60, 4))
                       .withColumn("date", substr(filename, 60, 10))
```

This is just a simple example, you can be more creative and use regEx functions. It depends on the structure of your path.

Step 4.

Remove unnecessary columns.

```
val outputDF = input3DF.drop("filename")
```

Step 5.

Write the DataFrame data to the target folder using **Parquet** format

```
outputDF.write.partitionBy("year", "date").parquet("s3://<targetpath>")
```

Following this approach, the files will end in folders like:

```
s3://<targetpath>/year=2023/date=20230115/<parquet-file>
```

NOTES:

1. To avoid create a huge amount of files in the ouput, consider **repartition** outputDF before write it.
2. Values of the columns used to create the partitions should follow the rules of the target filesystem to create valid foldernames (avoid spaces, symbols, etc)
3. Folders with names like `name=value` are the standard to define partition columns. Parquet reader know how to discover them and create columns based on those values. [Parquet - Partition discovery](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#partition-discovery)